# bootstrap toggle button is not collapsing

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a responsive site. **I first tried it in localhost and the theme worked fine**. I mean the bootstrap toggle button worked fine.**now I started the theme lively** and I also made some changes in the arrangements of widgets. now **the toggle button is not working**. nothing drops down when clicked. i tried so many times but can't figure out what is the issue. this is the [link](http://craniofacialcochin.com/) .please help me to fix this.

My header portion code which contains the menu.

```
<head>

 <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/ico/favicon.ico">

 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!--file inside the css folder-->

  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

   <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
  <?php //wp_head(); ?> 
  </head>
<body>           

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="border-bottom:1px solid #3379b4!important;">
<div  class="Top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="ContactDtls"><?php get_sidebar('contact'); ?></div>
      <div class="socialIcons"><?php get_sidebar('snicons');?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
  </button>
 <?php get_sidebar('logo'); ?></div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

 <?php get_sidebar('menu'); ?>

  </div>
<!--/.navbar-collapse --> 
 </div>
```

Functions.php

```
  function wpt_register_js() {
   wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.bootstrap.min');
   }add_action( 'init', 'wpt_register_js' );

  function wpt_register_css() {
  wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
   }add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_css' );
```

**Resolved**
 i skipped this link from header.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or some code instead of posting a link to your website: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: what you mean by toggle not working?

Comment: @jack: i mean when taking the mobile view the toggle button is coming but when i clicked on it nothing happens. usually when we click on the bootstrap toggle button the menu list will collapse ryt.? at here nothing is happening.

Comment: You are missing the boostrap.js file.

Comment: @jack: so can i include that like this "wp_register_script('jquery.bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', 'jquery'); " in functions.php

Comment: i tried with the above code that i commented now. but no change occur. still the same issue. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missed to load jquery library and bootstrap js files

Kindly add below code in head block

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i have included those thrgh functions.php sir. please find my updated post.

Comment: @user3493407 but your generated page does not have that files so check'

Comment: yeah now i got when i add jquery...oops what an idiot i am..didn't noticed that.. thanks alot sridhar.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the boostrap.js file.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not included javascript in your HTML

review this : http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

add this in your HTML

`<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: i have included those thrgh functions.php sir. please find my updated post.